# GWT: How to set text-align on com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style

Tags: gwt, coding-style, text-align

How to set `text-align` on com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style object?

Answer (score 6):

You can use setProperty (note property name is camel case):

```
style.setProperty("textAlign", "left");
```

Comment: That has to do with text-align, not with GWT. Text-align is buggy in IE http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-align

Comment: For CSS the text-align property is "text-align". When I tried doing "text-align" it throws an error complaining about "must be camelCase. Why do I have to do "textAlign"? isn't the above style.setProperty changing the CSS style? (I am noobish at this web stuff so you might have to explain a little more low level)

Comment: GWT needs the properties in camelCase (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), but then it tanslates them to CSS format. So you set "textAlign" in GWT, but the in the rendered page you will see "text-align"

Comment: More explicitly GWT is using the JavaScript names of the CSS properties. This is because GWT is inherently a JavaScript technology. See http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/javascript-property-names-for-css-getelementbyid/